# Jquery ajax call unable to detect 404 from the API

Tags: jquery

I am working on GitHub rest API, I am able to get the data of a username as soon as I enter the username in the input field. But the ajax call is not able to determine if the link to a user exists or not.

I can see a 404 (Not found) message printed on the console but the `#result` div never gets updated with the text `No users`.

```js
$('#username').on('keyup', function() {
  var name = $('#username').val(),
    requri = 'https://api.github.com/users/' + name;

  $.ajax({
    url: requri,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {

      if (data.message === "Not Found") {
        $("#result").html("No users");
      } else {
        $("#result").html("User found");
      }
      
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="get-user-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter github username" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because a 404 response does not go in to the `success` handler. It goes in to the `error` handler - assuming you define one.

However in this case as you're specifically looking for a 404 error to indicate the Github user does not exist you can place a handler function for a specific response code using the `statusCode` property:

```js
$('#username').on('keyup', function() {
  var name = $('#username').val(),
    requri = 'https://api.github.com/users/' + encodeURIComponent(name);

  $.ajax({
    url: requri,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      $("#result").html("User found");
    },
    error: function(x, s, e) {
      console.log('Something went wrong. Handle errors here...');
    },
    statusCode: {
      404: function() {
        $("#result").html("User not found");
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="get-user-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter github username" autocomplete="off">
  </div>
</form>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Note the use of `encodeURIComponent()` to ensure the value provided in the input is sanitised for use in the URL.

Comment: so let's say I want to handle some other error code then I have to make a callback function under the statusCode??

Comment: If you want to handle each statusCode individually, yes. You can just have a single 'catch all' in the `error` handler though. It depends entirely on how you want it to work.

Comment: Now the text in `#result` is changing but the red message still appears in the console. Will that be a problem??

Comment: No, not at all.

Answer (score 1):

404 is an error code, therefore the xhr will trigger the 'failure' handler, not the "success" handler.

```js
$.ajax({
  url: requri,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    $("#result").html("User found");
  },
  error: function(data) {
     $("#result").html("No users");
  }
});
```